# How to find the path chain of an included file in Visual Studio?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

Imagine that I have these `.targets` files:

- Base.targets
- Api.targets
- GameApi.targets

And this the their contents:

**Base.targets**

```
<Project>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="C:\Base\Database\Optimize.sql">
      <Link>Database\Optimize.sql</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Api.targets**

```
<Project>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="C:\Api\Database\Api.sql">
      <Link>Database\Api.js</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="C:\Base\Base.targets" />

</Project>
```

**GameApi.targets**

```
<Project>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="C:\GameApi\Database\GameApi.sql">
      <Link>Database\GameApi.js</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="C:\Api\Api.targets" />

</Project>
```

In fact we have a simple chain of inclusions of `.targets` files. Now when I import that `GameApi.targets` inside a project, I see the files being added as links to that project.

If I want to know the inclusion source of each file, I need to manually open each targets file and find out the line where that file is being included.

For a large hierarchy of `.targets` files it become impossible and very tedious.

Do we have a tool to show us that?

Comment: Did you want to show the path of the included files which are added as link? If so, you can write a custom target to show the whole path.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. I still couldn't get a free time to test it. I'll make sure to test it and accept it as the answer if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to know the inclusion source of each file, I need to
>   manually open each targets file and find out the line where that file
>   is being included.For a large hierarchy of .targets files it become
>   impossible and very tedious.

Try to create a custom target to show the item files' path, you can try these:

Solution

**1)** add these in your project's `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="Show_Path" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('%(None.Identity)'))"></Message>
</Target>
```

If you want to see `Content` node or `Compile` node or so on, you can add them too:

```
 <Target Name="Show_Path" AfterTargets="Build">

    <Message Importance="high" Text="$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('%(None.Identity)'))"></Message>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('%(Content.Identity)'))"></Message>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('%(Compile.Identity)'))"></Message>         

 </Target>
```

**Then**, you can build your project and after it, it will list on the output window.

**The effect is as follows**:

[image]

Comment: I tested this method, and it works great. However, for some projects I might not have Content or None or Compile nodes. Can I put conditions on them?

Comment: I get this error: `The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('')" cannot be evaluated. The path is not of a legal form.

Comment: While this worked, it's not what I want. I want to know From what targets file GameApi.sql is being included. In fact I wants to know the name of the targets files alongside the path of the files included.

Comment: Sure. You can add a condition to determine whether the file is empty. Like this:   `<Message Condition="Exists('%(None.Identity)')" Importance="high" Text="$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('%(None.Identity)'))"></Message>`.